# How to access data from Google Finance table with JSoup?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from the table where it states '**range**', '**52 week**', '**open**', etc... on this site: https://finance.google.com/finance?q=aapl&ei=czANWqmhNoPYswHV9YnwBg

The code below scrapes the write data but not in the format I want. It outputs the contents of the whole table as one string, whereas I would like each part of the table to be outputted separately on its own line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class JSoup {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String ticker = "AAPL";

    String url = "https://finance.google.com/finance?q="+ticker+"&ei=czANWqmhNoPYswHV9YnwBg";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();



    for (Element row : document.select("table.snap-data")) {
            final String key = row.select(".range").text();
            final String val = row.select(".val").text();
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.println(val);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are aware that this is against Google's Terms of Service, yes?

Comment: Even if I am using it for a school project? The program will not be used commercially.